# want to sort a list based on a condition that a1<=a2>=a3<=a4>=a5<=a6.....an

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sort a list based on a condition that `a1<=a2>=a3<=a4>=a5<=a6.....an`

Input: [a1, ... , an] (n numbers, not in order)
Output: ai1 <= ai2 >= ai3 <= ai4 >= ai5 <= ai6 ....

> Write Code Input: [a1, ... , an] (n numbers, not in order) return ai1 <= ai2 >= ai3 <= ai4 >= ai5 <= ai6 ....
>   Verify the code (test cases)
>   Input list =[1,4,7,9,1,3,5,10,11]
>   One of the Expected outcome is as follows
>   Output = 1, 9, 7, 10, 4, 5, 1, 11, 3

I tried the below code:

```py
l =[1,4,7,9,1,3,5,10,11]
s=[]
for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
    if i%2 ==0:
        if l[i]<= l[i+1]:
            s.append(l[i])
    else:
        if l[i] >= l[i+1]:
            s.append(l[i])
print(s)
```

The output is as follows:

```
[1, 7, 9, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what is the outcome of that instead of asking someone else to write code for you

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please have a read through [How do I ask homework/assignment questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) We expect that an attempt has been made.

Comment: There's not a single unique list ordering with the property you want. Does your test case code allow for multiple different solutions? For instance, the easiest way I can think of to do what you want is to sort the list, then interleave the first half and the second half. For your example input, that would end up with `[1, 7, 1, 9, 3, 10, 4, 11, 5]`, which has your desired property, but it is not the same output as you say you expect.

Comment: @Blckknght, Thank You for your response, The output that you have mentioned is fine, can you please tell how to do that.

Comment: @PatelRomil, Thank You for your response, Actually i tried for the solution, i edited the question with my trail code and output.

Comment: For such sort of question it is an (abstract) **algorithm** which should be selected first. Then you need to write a code which implements the algorithm selected. If you have problem with selecting the algorithm, use Blckknght's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56503011/#comment99595075_56503011). It is hard to say which algorithm your current code follows, so we cannot help your with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing in your output it seems there is no logic on how you got that output for the given test case. There are many possible outcomes, and the test case output is just one case. Do you need to generate all the possible outcomes or any one is enough?

If only one is enough the following code works well.

```py
l =[1,4,7,9,1,3,5,10,11]
l.sort()    # sort the array
s=[]
for i in range(len(l)//2):
    s.append(l[i])   # append some small value
    s.append(l[-i -1])    # append some large value
if len(l)%2:
    s.append(l[len(l)//2])   # for array with odd length
print(s)

>>> [1, 11, 1, 10, 3, 9, 4, 7, 5]
```

This code does not produce the test case output but it generates valid output in O(len(l)) time complexity.

Comment: But the output of the solution is [1, 11, 1, 10, 3, 9, 4, 7, 4] coming like this, not [1, 11, 1, 10, 3, 9, 4, 7, 5]

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake at s.append(len(l)//2) it should be s.append(l[len(l)//2]), I'll update my answer. thank you.

Comment: Thank you, But if we want all possible outcomes, then how can we do?

Comment: One straight forward way is to first sort the array, and then generate all permutations of the array. Then for every permutation you need to check whether that permutation matches your condition a1<=a2>=a3...  But this approach has a time complexity of O(n!) where n is the array length.